# Why won't this CSS for inverting colours on hover work on my image?

Tags: html, css

```css
#menuleaf:hover, #menuleaf:focus　{
  filter:invert(100%);
 }
```

```html
<img id="menuleaf" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/411/411289.svg" height=13px" />
```

What is the problem exactly? All the tutorials I can find make it seem like it should be as easy as this?

Comment: Is the image actually displaying on your webpage?

Comment: do you have a link to the specified page?

Comment: also your height is missing opening "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo:**

You have an invalid white-space character between `:focus` and `{`:

```js
const str= `#imgname:hover, #imgname:focus　{`;
console.log(str.split('focus')[1].charCodeAt(0)); // space is 32
```

Fixing this typo will make your rule work:

```css
#imgname:hover, #imgname:focus {
  filter:invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<img id="imgname" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg" height="13px" />
```

And also note that while it's not the issue here, your `height` attribute misses an opening  `"`.

Comment: That would be my Japanese keyboard. Did not even realize that was a thing. Thank you!!

Comment: Hm. That seemed to work perfectly on [codepen](https://codepen.io/brxtn/pen/byeMg) but as soon as I tried to do it on [my actual site](http://sandhals.ca/) it didn't work. The hover is meant for the small leaf icon.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on both Chrome and Firefox. Try resetting your cache (by doing an hard-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Your image source doesn't look like it would load correctly. Give the correct location of the image inside `src`.

then invert the image

```
#imgname:hover,#imgname:focus {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
          filter: invert(100%);
}
```